# How are components managed in Spring MVC and how to inject a customized component in Spring 3.2.5?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I’m considering to replace the **DefaultSessionAttributeStore** implementation of Spring MVC 3.2.5 with some class of my own, and I’ve known from the source code that in my 3.2.5 spring source, it’s **SessionAttributesHandler** which possesses a **SessionAttributeStore** interface reference and invokes the session store function. My question is how to replace that by DI? The SessionAttributesHandler holds a final private sessionAttributeStore reference and can only be set by the constructor:

```
public class SessionAttributesHandler {

    ...

    private final SessionAttributeStore sessionAttributeStore;

    ...


    public SessionAttributesHandler(Class<?> handlerType, SessionAttributeStore sessionAttributeStore) {
        Assert.notNull(sessionAttributeStore, "SessionAttributeStore may not be null.");
        this.sessionAttributeStore = sessionAttributeStore;

        SessionAttributes annotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(handlerType, SessionAttributes.class);
        if (annotation != null) {
            this.attributeNames.addAll(Arrays.asList(annotation.value()));
            this.attributeTypes.addAll(Arrays.<Class<?>>asList(annotation.types()));
        }

        for (String attributeName : this.attributeNames) {
            this.knownAttributeNames.put(attributeName, Boolean.TRUE);
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Are all the components of spring mvc managed in the spring DI container? How to inject my own SessionAttributeStore implementation into SessionAttributesHandler? What does the "Class handlerType" argument mean in the constructor? From source, it seems like it's the "controller" class. Since SessionAttributesHandler is invoked and held by a ModelFactory, and in ModelFactory there is no code instantiating the SessionAttributesHandler, is there any "XML" bean configuration file for the Spring MVC inner components and how to overwrite them?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to provide your own implementation of a `SessionAttributeStore` you need to manually configure the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`  and set your custom implementation on there. That will take care of using it through-out the rest of the infrastructure.

Assuming that you use java config you can do the following

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration extend WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public SessionAttributeStore sessionAttributeStore() {
        return new MyCustomSessionAttributeStore();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter() {
        RequestMappingHandlerAdapter rmha = super.requestMappingHandlerAdapter();
        rmha.setSessionAttributeStore(sessionAttributeStore());
        return rmha;
    }

}
```

If you want to do this in XML you either have to write a `BeanPostProcessor` which sets it on the default `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` instance created by `<mvc:annotation-driven />` or configure it manually and drop the namespace support.